# How to restrict the inserting a record through a oracle trigger

Tags: plsql

I want to restrict the records which are inserting into table a where i am creating trigger on that of before insert.
I have a scenario

```
Table A
  id number
  id1 number
Table B
  id number
Table c
  id number
Table D
  id number
  id1 number
```

My code:

```
create or replace trigger trg_a --trigger name
  before insert on a
  for each row
    declare
      v_id b.id%type;
      v_id1 c.id%type;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;  
    begin
      select id into v_id from b where id=:NEW.id;
      select id into v_id1 from c where id=:NEW.id; 
      if(:NEW.id=v_id or :NEW.id=v_id1) then
        insert into d
          (id,id1,name)
        values(:NEW.id,:NEW.id1,:NEW.name);
      end if;
      delete from a where id =v_id or id 1=v_id1 ; --matched id
      commit;
    end;  --end statement
```

It is inserting for matching records with the look up tables i.e. `b`, `c` and parallel `y` also inserting into table `a`. This record insertion need to restrict so I have kept delete statement but it is not working.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and indent your code for readability, please?

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do this in separate transaction. I don't see the reason for this and this is also causing your code doesn't work as desired.

Probably you didn't commit after each insert, so when new transaction was started inside trigger body it didn't see any records in table A to be deleted.

I left out pragma autonomous_transaction and commit; and now it deletes records from table as you expected. 
(Note that I made some changes to your code, because it was unable to compile, due to non existent NAME column and id 1)

```
create or replace trigger trg_a --trigger name
before insert on a
for each row
declare
  v_id b.id%type;
  v_id1 c.id%type;
--pragma autonomous_transaction;  
begin
  select id into v_id from b where id=:NEW.id;
  select id into v_id1 from c where id=:NEW.id; 
  if(:NEW.id=v_id or :NEW.id=v_id1) then
    insert into d
      (id,id1)
    values(:NEW.id,:NEW.id1);
  end if;
  delete from a where id =v_id or id1=v_id1 ; --matched id
  --commit;
end;  
/
```

So either commit after each insert or ommit autonomous transaction.

UPDATE:
Now you made it clear, that you don't want to insert into table a at all. Since INSTEAD OF trigger works only on views, I fear that only way how to achieve this it to cause runtime exception, so that Insert into A will be not succesfull however INSERT into table D will succeed. Look at this, on purpose it causes on insert PL/SQL numeric or value error, when assigning varchar value to number columns

```
create or replace trigger trg_a --trigger name
  before insert on a
  for each row
   declare
  v_id b.id%type;
  v_id1 c.id%type;
 pragma autonomous_transaction;  
  begin
  select id into v_id from b where id=:NEW.id;
  select id into v_id1 from c where id=:NEW.id; 
  if(:NEW.id=v_id or :NEW.id=v_id1) then
    insert into d
      (id,id1)
    values(:NEW.id,:NEW.id1);
  end if;
  delete from a where id =v_id or id1=v_id1 ; --matched id
  commit;
   :NEW.id:=null;
   :NEW.id1:='a';
end;  
 /
```

Comment: Thanks Mina.But the records are inserting to table a.

Comment: insert into a values(100,101)  --this 100 is from table b and 101 from c when I issued above insert statement it is inserting into table a and also table d.Need to restrict the table a insertion.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mina.After trigger not working,inserting records to table a. I think instead of trigger can be created on views. I Need to think other than trigger option.

Comment: But this will not work. insert into a values(100,101);

1 row created.                                                                                     select * from a;

        ID        ID1
---------- ----------     here table showing null record.I want to reject that record being inserted

Comment: Here i have taken :NEW.id1 :=NULL because datatype is defined as number

Comment: If datatype of column is defined as number and you change :NEW to varchar e.g  'somestring' it will definitely cause runtime exception Numeric or value error. I tried it, it works: No rows inserted into A, row inserted into D

Comment: SQL> insert into a values(100,101);
insert into a values(100,101)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_A", line 17
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_A'


Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL> select * from d;

no rows selected  but records not inserted into table d.How you got

Comment: Did you put back the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION and COMMIT; ? Now it has it's reason, since insert into D is made in separate transaction and it is not rolled back by Exception

Comment: yes it is inserting only to table d. But raising exception that numeric or value_error and coming out from program so it is not inserting into table a.But if i handled this exception in exception block with others exception then it is inserting into table a. I donot want to program exit with error as well as restrict the record to table a. Thanks

Comment: I donot want to program exit with error at the same i need to restrict the record to table a. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid there is only one last option left. Is your insert made by the same user as is owner of table A, is it in same schema ? If not you can create a view, instead of trigger on view, and public synonym on this view with name A; i tried it under SYS and it works. Otherwise if  insert is execured from the same schema, I'm almost sure there is no way to do want you want.

Comment: Thanks Mina. For trigger delete only old values or null values will be available so  i have assigned new values as null for both the ids and deleting the records with that assigned values but still why trigger is inserting a null value to the table a.(When i queried with select it is showing null values).I am not sure it is bug of trigger.So lets i will try with instead of trigger. Thank you very much..

Comment: Yeah, now i have solved problem with instead of trigger.

Comment: It's not the bug of the trigger it works very much like it is supposed to, first deletes records and then inserts null values. Also now if you switched to instead of trigger you can rename your table and create view with the name A, so user will not notice it is not inserting in former table

Answer (score 0):

If you have 11g or later, you may want to look at using a compound trigger.

```
Create Or Replace Trigger Trg_A
For Insert On A
Compound Trigger
    Type Id_T Is Table Of A.Id%type Index By Simple_Integer;
    Id_List   Id_T;
    Id_ndx    simple_integer := 0;
    Id_Count  Integer;

    After Each Row Is Begin
        -- If the same id is in Table B or Table C
        Select Count(*) Into Id_Count From B Where Id = :New.ID;
        If Id_Count = 0 Then
            -- Only check C if nothing in B
            Select Count(*) Into Id_Count From C Where Id = :New.ID;
        End If;
        If Id_Count > 0 Then
            -- If already in B or C, log to D
            Insert Into D( Id, Id1, Name )
            Values( :New.ID, :New.ID, :New.Name);
            -- Then save for later deletion from A
            Id_ndx  := Id_ndx + 1;
            Id_List( Id_ndx ) := :New.Id;
        End If;
    End After Each Row;
    After Statement Is Begin
        Forall Idx In 1 .. Id_ndx
            -- Delete saved IDs (if any)
            Delete From A Where Id = Id_List( Idx );
        Id_List.Delete();
        Id_ndx := 0;
    End After Statement;
End;
```

The problem is that it is tricky using an autonomous transaction pragma in a compound trigger. It may not even be possible, I just don't have any experience with that pragma.

However, several people have mentioned "instead of" triggers on views. When I design a database, almost all DML goes through views, many of those views exist for no other reason. Many times a table will have multiple views so DML can take place no matter how the data is being accessed. I can't begin to tell you how many problems this solves. So you may want to take a serious look at that option.